# The Destination is read-only

Tags: dual-boot, read-only

I have dual booted my pc with Ubuntu 18.04 and Windows10. 
I am having trouble using one of my disk drives. Like whenever I try to used the DATA drive it shows error: The Destination is read-only.

I checked a solution for this and one says to use ntfsfix. Then another says not to use that as it may corrupt the windows file system. 
Please let me know how to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

Windows locks the ntfs drives while it's using them. If you don't shutdown your windows correctly (any error while shutting down, hibernating, or having fast start up enabled) ntfs drives will stay locked and can only be mounted as read only if you don't want to risk corruption.
You should check if your windows has been shut down correctly and try [disabling fast start up](https://help.uaudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/213195423-How-To-Disable-Fast-Startup-in-Windows-10) and making sure you don't turn off windows by any abnormal means like holding the power button and the problem should be fixed.

If the said drive is fat32, you should set the owner of the mounted drive by mounting it with this command:

```
sudo mount -t vfat -o rw,uid=myname,gid=users /dev/sdb1 /media/usb
```

replace 'myname' with your user name and 'users' with your user group. more info on this part in [this](https://superuser.com/questions/915596/how-to-change-usergroup-for-fat32-usb-drive) question.

Comment: Hey @mpower thanks for your reply.
I haven't tried what you've suggested rather I first tried <chmod 777> command with the filesystem path. And then restarted my system. The problem solved.
God forbid if anything goes wrong again I will give yours a try.